# What are the major models for energy derivatives, particularly electricity derivatives?

Tags: options, derivatives

Aside from Black-Scholes with crazy skews, what major models are used for energy derivatives?  I'm thinking particularly of electricity derivatives, but I'm also interested in natural gas and other volatile contracts(*).

(*): pun intended

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a complicated question.   There are many paths.

One path is to build a model of the underlying supply/demand relationships.   For example, the sudden loss of a power supplier (or transmision corridor) shifts the supply curve to the left spiking the price.   The key to the game is data, data, and more data (price, weather/wind, season, power loads, current power generation, stand-by generation, transmission line overload, etc).

There are several books written on the subject.  If you dig around, you'll find everything from over-simplified books, to books that over-kill on a specific area of the business.    Just a quick Google gives:

[http://www.amazon.com/Managing-Energy-Price-Risk-Challenges/dp/1904339190](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1904339190)

[http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Todays-Electricity-Business-Shively/dp/0974174416](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0974174416)

My reputation level is too low to post more links.

Comment: do you have any good sources for an introduction to supply/demand modelling in commodities?

Comment: @Permian,   Here's a link to a simple electrical demand model using monthly data:  https://revgr.com/2012/11/06/all-forecasts-are-wrong-but-some-generate-fewer-complaints/     Here's the Youtube video for that article:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzxOjdix614&t=81s    You'll have to do some digging for a supply model.

Answer (score 4):

This [guy](http://commoditymodels.com/2010/02/25/key-papers-in-commodities-finance/) listed a list of key papers relative to commodities price modeling. That could perhaps help you get started.